# How To export Database(MySql) from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using first time AWS & I am able to login, now, I want to export database, how can i do this

I have tried but I do not know to export DB, somebody help me to go in right direction my dashboard looks like this

[image]

Comment: are you using aws mysql RDS instance ?

Comment: Your question is not related to programming and does not belong here. You'll find better help on the AWS documentation site (https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/) that is related to the type of the database you're using, or you can browse the Discussion Forums (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa)

Comment: What type of database? Have you looked at any documentation? If so, what was it that didn't work?

Comment: Hi I am sorry for late reply..I have updated my screenshot please take a look

Comment: HI @RahulSingh , welcome to SO , please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: That's just a picture of the list of AWS services. It is the same thing everyone sees when they login to AWS. Your screenshot provides no information about your question at all. If you can't even specify what type of database you are using in your question then we aren't going to be able to help you.

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of database.
For example to export MySQL DB follow [these](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html) steps. It shows how to replicate MySQL DB using mysqldump